# integral of $e^{-ix}$ in three ways

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTfku.jpg)

I calcultaed this integral in three different ways. contour integral, fourier TF and obvious way.

I've seen this integral depends on distribution. if we just calculate this with normal way, apprently it diverges, but given (Schwartz) distribution, it's gonna be dirac-delta distribution.

I also solved this integral with complex contour integral. but in this way, it concludes -i which contradicts above conclusions.

so here are my questions

1. I assumed that this integral just depends on how we tackle. Am I correct?
2. Is the last way with complex integral correct?

Thank you.

Comment: What you've really proved is that when you take something undefined, you can prove it equals anything you want, almost to the point of meaninglessness. For example, if I asked you what Green was without any context, you would say it is a color. But if I was reading off a list of famous mathematicians, then Green was a person, not a color. Integrals that converge will have an unambiguous answer with the least amount of context. Integrals that diverge will require lots of context and different contexts will produce different results - with neither being more correct or wrong than the others.